# Add fbox to the numbering of each section, subsection, and subsubsection in the Arabic language

Tags: numbering, polyglossia, arabic, amsart

I would like to add fbox to the numbering of each section, subsection, and subsubsection to make it look like the following but for

```
Arabic language \usepackage{polyglossia}
```

[image]

When I add the following commands

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\fbox{\Roman{section}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\fbox{\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\fbox{\alph{subsubsection}}}
```

I got the result, but for polyglossia Arabic mode doesn't work. It looks like that

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\thesection{\fbox{\Roman{section}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\fbox{\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\fbox{\alph{subsubsection}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
    \section{اتصال}
    \subsection{اتصال في نقطة}
    \subsection{اتصال في مجال}
    \subsubsection{مبرهنة القيم الوسيطية}
    \section{اشتقاق}
    \subsection{اشتقاق في نقطة}
    \subsubsection{اشتقاق في المجال}
\end{document}
```

Could you please help me to fix this for the Arabic language using the polyglossia package? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably do the `\renewcommands` after loading the language packages, or else they might get undone.

Also, I would probably try using the [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec?lang=en) package to customize the title format. Using the `explicit` option gives you more leeway. Since arabic is right-to-left, though, you need to reverse the order in the commands.

I can't read Arabic myself, so I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but my best guess would be something like this. You probably want to tweak the font size (here `\large`) and possibly the alignment (`\flushleft`), etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand\thesection{\fbox{\Roman{section}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\fbox{\arabic{subsection}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\fbox{\begin{english}\textit{\alph{subsubsection}}\end{english}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\flushleft\large}{#1\ \thesection}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\flushleft\large}{#1\ \thesubsection}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\flushleft\large}{#1\ \thesubsubsection}{0pt}{}
\begin{document}
    \section{اتصال}
    \subsection{اتصال في نقطة}
    \subsection{اتصال في مجال}
    \subsubsection{مبرهنة القيم الوسيطية}
    \section{اشتقاق}
    \subsection{اشتقاق في نقطة}
    \subsubsection{اشتقاق في المجال}
\end{document}
```

[image: arabic titles]

Comment: Almost what I want, but I would like to have them from right to left. Thank you.

Comment: You mean you want the numbers on the right? Then change, e.g., `{#1\ \thesection}` to `{\thesection\ #1}`.

Comment: A (likely serious) downside of this approach is that cross-references to sections, subsections, etc will be generated with frameboxes drawn around the section, subsection, etc numbers. I can't imagine anyone would want to do that.

Comment: If you want to get around the problem Mico points to, you could move the `\fbox` commands from within the `\renewcommand`s to inside the `\titleformat` commands, e.g., `{\fbox{\thesection}\ #1}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses an approach I learned years ago from the book "The LaTeX Companion". It doesn't redefine the macros `\thesection`, `\thesubsection`, etc. Instead, it uses the very-low-level LaTeX macros `\section@cntformat`, `\subsection@cntformat`, etc. to draw rectangular frames aroud the section, subsection, and subsubsection numbers in the sectioning headers. A major advantage of this approach is that you can create cross-references to sections, subsections, etc *without* (presumably) unwanted frameboxes showing up.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Amiri}

% Method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed.:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%    default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\fbox{\thesection}\space}       % section
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\fbox{\thesubsection}\space} % subsection
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{\fbox{\thesubsubsection}\space} % subsection
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section{اتصال}
    \subsection{اتصال في نقطة}
    \subsection{اتصال في مجال}
    \subsubsection{مبرهنة القيم الوسيطية}
    \section{اشتقاق}
    \subsection{اشتقاق في نقطة}
    \subsubsection{اشتقاق في المجال}
\end{document}
```

If you want a trailing `.` ("dot") to be included in the frame box, just change

```
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\fbox{\thesection}\space}
```

to

```
\newcommand\section@cntformat{\fbox{\thesection.}\space}
```

and similarly for `\subsection@cntformat` and `\subsection@cntformat`.

---

Incidentally, *without* the option `numerals=maghrib`, one would obtain the following result:

[image]